# Unable to make OpenCV

Tags: macos, opencv, makefile, osx-snow-leopard

I downloaded OpenCV 2.3.1 from the OpenCV website and unpacked it to `/usr/share/src`.  I ran `sudo cmake .` in that folder to generate the make files, and then ran "`sudo make`"  I'm getting the following error:

> [ 20%] Building CXX object
>   modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/loadsave.o
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:298:
>   error: ‘InputArray’ has not been declared
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In
>   function ‘bool cv::imwrite(const std::string&, int, const
>   std::vector >&)’:
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:301:
>   error: request for member ‘getMat’ in ‘_img’, which is of non-class
>   type ‘int’
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In
>   function ‘void* cv::imdecode_(const cv::Mat&, int, int, cv::Mat*)’:
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:312:
>   error: ‘tempfile’ was not declared in this scope
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: At
>   global scope:
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392:
>   error: ‘cv::Mat cv::imdecode’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
>
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:107: error: previous
>   declaration of ‘cv::Mat cv::imdecode(const cv::Mat&, int)’
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392:
>   error: ‘InputArray’ was not declared in this scope
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392:
>   error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:399:
>   error: ‘InputArray’ has not been declared
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In
>   function ‘bool cv::imencode(const std::string&, int,
>   std::vector >&, const
>   std::vector >&)’:
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:402:
>   error: request for member ‘getMat’ in ‘_image’, which is of non-class
>   type ‘int’
>
> /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:427:
>   error: ‘tempfile’ was not declared in this scope
>
> make[2]: ***
>   [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/loadsave.o] Error 1
>
> make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error

Why is this?  How can I fix it?  Thanks

The full error is as follows:

```
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool CvCapture_FFMPEG::grabFrame()’:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:638: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3454)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:640: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3454)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp: In member function ‘bool CvVideoWriter_FFMPEG::open(const char*, int, double, int, int, bool)’:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1339: warning: ‘guess_format’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:789)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1339: warning: ‘guess_format’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:789)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1367: warning: ‘av_alloc_format_context’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:947)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:1367: warning: ‘av_alloc_format_context’ is deprecated (declared at /opt/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:947)
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:298: error: ‘InputArray’ has not been declared
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In function ‘bool cv::imwrite(const std::string&, int, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:301: error: request for member ‘getMat’ in ‘_img’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In function ‘void* cv::imdecode_(const cv::Mat&, int, int, cv::Mat*)’:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:312: error: ‘tempfile’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: At global scope:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392: error: ‘cv::Mat cv::imdecode’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
/opt/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp:107: error: previous declaration of ‘cv::Mat cv::imdecode(const cv::Mat&, int)’
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392: error: ‘InputArray’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:392: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:399: error: ‘InputArray’ has not been declared
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp: In function ‘bool cv::imencode(const std::string&, int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:402: error: request for member ‘getMat’ in ‘_image’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:427: error: ‘tempfile’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/loadsave.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the instructions under **Use CMake to Build** in section 2 of [the Wiki](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port):

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Comment: Probably you need to remove `/usr/share/src/OpenCV-2.3.1` and unpack a clean sources from tarball before the build with wiki's instructions.

Comment: This has worked for me as well.  I've also seen it fail when I have other software installed using fink. (In this case, I temporarily moved the fink /sw directory to something else, so it wouldnt be found in various paths while I'm doing the cmake/make)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a conflict with an earlier installation of MacPorts. 
Run:

```
port installed opencv
```

If this finds another version of opencv then use:

```
sudo port deactivate opencv
```

Then run make again.

Note: it will brake anything that was depending on your previous opencv ports install. So you'll need to activate old again or adjust dependencies to use 2.3.1.